# pInvokeStackImbalance MDA Warning how to fix it

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

i'm trying to invoke this in my c# application

```
    [DllImport("UOEncryption.dll")]
    public static extern void Decompress([In, Out] byte[] dest, byte[] src, out int dest_size, ref int src_size, ref HuffmanObj obj);

    [DllImport("UOEncryption.dll")]
    public static extern void DecompressClean(ref HuffmanObj obj);
```

the signatures in c are

```
    void Decompress(char *dest, const char *src, int *dest_size, int *src_size, HuffmanObj *obj);
    void DecompressClean(HuffmanObj *obj);
```

I don't know how it's wrong.

Thank you

Comment: By specifying the CallingConventions the problem is solved :)
Thank you very much
P.s. the HuffmanObj is a struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the CallingConvention property in the [DllImport] declaration, it is Cdecl in your case.  The default is StdCall, that will indeed trigger the MDA warning.

The *ref* keyword on the HuffmanObj looks wrong too, assuming you declared it as a class instead of a struct.  Do try to debug the native code so you can look at the passed argument values and quickly see a problem like this.  Project + Properties, Debug tab, Enable unmanaged code debugging checkbox.  Set a breakpoint on the first line in the native function body.

Comment: By specifying the CallingConventions the problem is solved :)
Thank you very much
P.s. the HuffmanObj is a struct.